# How can I add and modify shapes in an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Does anyone know a way of getting around the fact that shapes are not supported in `openpyxl`?

Is there a different library or code that I can use to achieve this??

I tried manipulating an excel file that had shapes and when my app saved the file, the shapes were gone.

Answer (score -1):

Try [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) library. It has the ability to add and modify shapes.

For example:

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book('example.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets[0]
sht.shapes.add_shape(1, 1, 2, 2, 'circle')
wb.save()
```

More information here https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#shapes

Comment: I haven't been able to make and edit to the answer 'queue full'. The add shape line **sht.shapes.add_shape(1, 1, 2, 2, 'circle')** will fail 'add_shape' is an invalid attribute and the sizes used are too small to see the circle. Use **sht.api.Shapes.AddShape(9, 1, 1, 20, 20)**   Note: Xlwings requires Excel installed locally, and not every function necessarily works on MACOS